# Adding wallpaper on logon screen or lock screen [windows8.1 and 8]

Tags: windows

Are there any ways I can add image/wallpaper on this lock/logon screen?
I already tried searching about it and I can't found anything.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKZBB.jpg

Answer (score 0):

the image is windows 8 logon screen. there is a software call logostudio. it is free and you can find it here http://www.stardock.com/ this campany makes a grat sofwere that can custmize windows in your style.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 8.1 you can do this very easily. You can find the official Microsoft topic here:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-8/desktop-background-lock-screen

> **To change your lock screen picture**
>
> You can choose just one favorite photo to use as a lock screen
>   picture, or pick a few to create a lock screen slide show.
>
> Swipe in from the right edge of the screen, tap Settings, then tap
>   Change PC settings. (If you're using a mouse, point to the
>   bottom-right corner of the screen, move the mouse pointer up, click
>   Settings, then click Change PC settings.)
>
> Tap or click PC and devices, then tap or click Lock screen.
>
> If you want to use just one photo on your lock screen, tap or click
>   Browse, and then choose the picture you want (you can choose photos on
>   your PC or OneDrive).
>
> Tap or click the picture you want to use to select it, then tap or
>   click Choose Image.
>
> To play a slide show on your lock screen, tap or click Play a slide
>   show on the lock screen to turn it on.
>
> Tap or click Add a folder and browse to the folder where you saved the
>   pictures you want to use.
>
> Tap or click the folder to select it, tap or click Choose this folder,
>   then tap or click OK. You can pick up to ten folders.